# Swift: Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '([Idea], from: Data)'

Tags: json, swift, persistence, jsondecoder, swift-structs

I've been trying to figure out the best solution for data persistence for an app I'm working on and I decided a locally stored JSON file will be the best balance of simplicity and functionality.

What I need to save is an array of custom structs, and I can write it just fine using the code below, but I can't decode it back, I'm getting this error:

> Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '([Idea], from:
>   Data)'

Any idea what's causing this? Is the ideas array itself supposed to be Codable? Encoding it shouldn't have worked then right? Am I doing something else wrong?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
var ideas = [Idea]()
```

--

```
struct Idea: Codable {
    var title: String
    var description: String?
    var date: String
    var completed: Bool
}
```

--

```
func writeIdeasToJSON(){
    let pathDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    try? FileManager().createDirectory(at: pathDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
    let filePath = pathDirectory.appendingPathComponent("data.json")

    let json = try? JSONEncoder().encode(ideas)

    do {
        try json!.write(to: filePath)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to write JSON data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

--

```
func readIdeasFromJSON(){
    do {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json")
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))

        do {
            let readIdeas = try JSONDecoder().decode(ideas.self, from: jsonData)
            print(readIdeas)
        } catch let error{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `[Idea].self` instead of `ideas.self`.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, but that results in a crash that just says 'Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' with no other details.

Comment: That's because it fixed the compiler error and now you are getting a completely unrelated runtime error. Most likely, `jsonData` is nil because your file isn't actually in your app's resource bundle. Which makes sense because you wrote the file to the Documents folder. Two completely different places.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So the first function saves it to the Documents folder, do you know what the correct way to reference that is?

Comment: Use the same code to get the path just as you did when saving.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, it returns: The file “data.json” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

I checked the path in both functions and it is the same if I use the same code.

Comment: See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues. First is the compiler error from:

```
let readIdeas = try JSONDecoder().decode(ideas.self, from: jsonData)
```

That needs to be :

```
let readIdeas = try JSONDecoder().decode([Idea].self, from: jsonData)
```

With that fixed you get a runtime error because you wrote the file to the Documents folder but you attempt to read it from the app's resource bundle.

Update your loading code to use the same path used to save the file:

```
func readIdeasFromJSON(){
    do {
        let pathDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let filePath = pathDirectory.appendingPathComponent("data.json")

        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: filePath)
        let readIdeas = try JSONDecoder().decode([Idea].self, from: jsonData)
        print(readIdeas)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot. Though as you've pointed out earlier it's [Idea]. Would you mind if I asked why that is? I thought I was decoding the array itself. That is what I encoded.

Comment: The `ideas` variable is not used at all when decoding. You have to tell `decode` what type to decode. You don't pass it a variable. If anything, you might have used `ideas = try JSONDecoder().decode([Idea].self, from: jsonData)`.

Comment: I understand. Thanks again for clarifying and helping me out.

Comment: If I may ask about one more thing: is there a way to have the function accept other types of objects too? So Idea, Goal, etc. I tried passing a parameters object: [Any] but then I get the same error from earlier Cannot invoke 'decode'..

Comment: Thanks, but there are already a few duplicate questions with one or two answers that I don't understand and I don't want to create yet another. I'll just make an ugly if statement (I only have 3 types) and revisit this later when I understand Generics better.